# Grouping data based on two logics

Tags: sorting, sed

I have a huge text file of 4 columns. The first column is a serial number, second and third columns are co-ordinates and 4th column is a value. These are the values of a variable at cell nodes. I would like to average the 4 nodal values to get the cell value to be read by my code. For example let me consider a 3 by 3 cartesian cell with following data:

```
1     0.     0.     5e-4
2     0.1     0.     5e-3
3     0.2     0.     5e-4
4     0.3     0.     5e-3
5     0.     0.1     5e-5
6     0.1     0.1     5e-7
7     0.2     0.1     5e-5
8     0.3     0.1     5e-2
9     0.     0.2     5e-4
10     0.1     0.2     5e-3
11     0.2     0.2     5e-4
12     0.3     0.2     5e-3
13     0.     0.3     5e-5
14     0.1     0.3     5e-7
15     0.2     0.3     5e-5
16     0.3     0.3     5e-2
```

I would like to group lines in the following order:

```
1     0.     0.     5e-4
2     0.1     0.     5e-3
5     0.     0.1     5e-5
6     0.1     0.1     5e-7
2     0.1     0.     5e-3
3     0.2     0.     5e-4
6     0.1     0.1     5e-7
7     0.2     0.1     5e-5
3     0.2     0.     5e-4
4     0.3     0.     5e-3
7     0.2     0.1     5e-5
8     0.3     0.1     5e-2
5     0.     0.1     5e-5
6     0.1     0.1     5e-7
9     0.     0.2     5e-4
10     0.1     0.2     5e-3
6     0.1     0.1     5e-7
7     0.2     0.1     5e-5
10     0.1     0.2     5e-3
11     0.2     0.2     5e-4 and so on ...
```

There are two logics in the above example. One, data of lines (1,2,5,6 and 2,3,6,7 and 3,4,7,8) form one set (the first row of my mesh). This is followed by lines (5,6,9,10) where we move on to the next row data. Then the first logic continues again (6,7,10,11 and 7,8,11,12 and so on...).

I used the following 'sed' command to extract group of lines but doing this individually is cumbersome considering the size of data I have to handle:

```
sed -n -e 1,2p -e 5,6p fileName
```

How can I create a loop considering both the logics that I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;N;s/\n/&/5;Ta;P;s/[^\n]*\n//;h;P;s/.*\n\(.*\n.*\)/\1/p;g;ba' file |
sed '13~12,+3d'
```

This follows the pattern uniformly i.e. lines 1,2 followed by lines 5,6, lines row 2,3 followed by lines 6,7 etc. The result is passed to second invocation of sed that removes 4 lines every 12 lines starting at line 13.